# Число кратно 10 увеличивался счетчик?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как для текстового поля создать счетчик, который увеличивался на один при кратности символов введенных на 10?

Comment: Вы бы пример привели текста и результаты счётчика.

Comment: В форму водим произвольный текст, например: аывавыаываыва. 13 символов. Счетчик должен показать, сколько раз по 10 символов в форме текста присутствует. В данном случае один раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подсчёта кратности вам необходимо разность общей длинны введённой строки и остатка от деления(деление по модулю) общей длинны строки разделить на 10.

```js
function counter(event) {
  const len = this.value.length;
  
  const count = (len - len % 10) / 10;

  console.log(`Общая длинна введённой строки: ${len} символ(ов)`);

  console.log(`Кратно 10: ${count} раз(а)`);
}

const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('change', counter);
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки кратности можно использовать деление по модулю x % 10